# How to multiply columns of a tibble by corresponding rows or columns of another tibble in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble, mapply

I am trying to multiply columns of a tibble by rows of another tibble in R. I tried sweep and match from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68426430/multiply-values-across-each-column-by-weight-in-another-data-frame-in-r) but it only uses one vector (one column of the second tibble). A small sample of my first dataset looks like:

| t_mode | ch_value | purpose | sov | ownership | age_16 | joint | atwork | sov_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SHARED | 2.06 | eat | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0.12 |
| SHARED | 2.19 | eat | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.08 |
| WALK | 2.45 | eat | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0.02 |
| PAY | 2.30 | eat | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.18 |
| PAY | 2.09 | eat | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.12 |
| ALONE | 1.82 | work | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.03 |
| SHARED | 0.2 | work | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0.14 |

and a small sample of the second dataset looks like:

| Expression | ALONE | SHARED | WALK | PAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sov | -999 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| ownership | -999 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| age_16 | -999 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| joint | -999 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| atwork | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| sov_time | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

The actual datasets are very large (1000 rows and 100k columns). I would appreciate it if anyone could help me find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be:

```
df1 %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(across(all_of(df2$Expression), ~ . * df2[match(cur_column(), df2$Expression), match(t_mode, names(df2))]))

  t_mode ch_value purpose   sov ownership age_16 joint atwork sov_time
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   <int>     <int>  <int> <int>  <int>    <dbl>
1 SHARED     2.06 eat         0         0      0     0      0     0   
2 SHARED     2.19 eat         0         0      0     0      0     0   
3 WALK       2.45 eat         0         1      0     1      0     0   
4 PAY        2.3  eat         0         0      0     0      0     0   
5 PAY        2.09 eat         0         0      0     0      0     0   
6 ALONE      1.82 work        0         0      0     0      0     0.03
7 SHARED     0.2  work        0         0      0     0      0     0
```

Comment: It does the job, thank you very much. The only issue is I had about 500 variables before multiplication, but after running this code I have more than 5000 columns! Column names look like "sov_time.WALK" and there are a lot of NAs. Is there a way to improve it?